# Sonar.tests property for test class

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

My java package has both source and junit in same package then, how to define sonar.tests property for the below case?

Source file: /src/java/ABC/Hello.java

Test file.    : /src/java/ABC/HelloUnitTest.java

And seems the property only looks for directories not files to separate them.

Comment: It is not possibile. Which build tool do you use? Maybe you could move test classes to other directory (package can be the same).

Comment: Jenkins... So any idea on sonar.sources... Would that be class files or java files

Comment: I asked about the build tool: `Maven`, `Ant`, `Gradle`? Please attach build script.

Comment: It is ant ... Problem is it is monolithic application so can't move now